# How to include a dollar sign in plotmath for ggplot2::label_parsed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I cannot include a dollar sign in facet labels using `labeller = label_parsed` in `ggplot2`. I'd like to include both a dollar sign and a superscript in the facet label, but I cannot determine how to make a dollar sign in plotmath. If there is a better way to accomplish this, that would also be helpful.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
library(ggplot2)

ex <- "hello~world~($/m^2)"

dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, g = ex)

ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ g, labeller = label_parsed)
```

Escaping the `$` with either `\$` or `\\$` does not work. I have tried on both Windows and Linux. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add quotes to the characters that are giving you trouble (parenthesis and dollars sign) to take them as strings. Here is a workaround.

```
library(ggplot2)

ex <- 'hello~world~"($"/m^2*")"'

dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, g = ex)

ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ g,labeller = label_parsed)
```

[image: Plot with facet name with $ symbol]

Answer (score 1):

Is applying the label manually feasible?

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ g, labeller = label_bquote(`hello~world~($/m^2)`))
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: I wanted to have the superscript 2 in addition to the dollar sign, so this doesn't really solve the problem unfortunately.